# Jenkins Ansible: How to get Ansible resources to slaves

Tags: ansible, jenkins

we plan to use jenkins and ansible to manage our environment: one jenkins master and a number of jenkins slaves. The slaves have ansible deployt.

The ansible playbooks and roles are generated from a central source - the same with the jenkins pipeline jobs. We generate releases of all the stuff: Jenkins pipelines and Ansible playbooks and roles. Typically we generate release artifacts in Nexus or Subversion ( as a Tag ).

Getting the pipelines to jenkins is easy ( JOB-DSL or from SCM ).

My Question: How to get the release playbooks and roles to the jenkins slaves where they are needed.

The options we thought about:

1. At releasetime go through all the slaves and install the new version. Drawback: Slaves could be dynamic; need to make sure all slaves have the right version.
2. Grap the resources at every playbook call. Drawback: Even small things require downloading ansible playbooks and roles.

What are your thoughts towards that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to get the playbooks to the slaves would be using SCM. As a playbook can easly depend on a specific Ansible version I would recommend to run Ansible playbook [inside a Docker container](https://medium.com/@tech_phil/running-ansible-inside-docker-550d3bb2bdff) on the Jenkins slaves rather than trying to maintain Ansible executables and dependencies. That way you can pin the Ansible version of a playbook and managed other runtime dependencies for Ansible.